# Foreign key constraint from varchar to enum field using MySql

Tags: mysql, enums, constraints, foreign-key-relationship, varchar

Let say I have an already existing table within my MySql database. This table has a field which is defined like this:

```
`field_a` enum('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3')
```

Now I'd like to define another table with `field_b`. `field_b` is supposed to reference `field_a` due to a foreign key constraint. Defining `field_b` as the exact `enum` type like `field_a` seams to be redundant. Is there a way to make `field_b` of type `varchar` and still referencing the `enum` in order to make sure, only valid values of the appropriate `enum` are written into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know from theory and practice, it's not possible now. Also, [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to `FOREIGN KEY` states:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types.

Now, although `ENUM` and `VARCHAR` are both classified as [string types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html), they're not considered similar data types. (Similar enough for this purpose at least). Only one data type that I've experimentally found to be similar to `ENUM` is `SET`. But even in case of using references `ENUM`-to-`ENUM` or `ENUM`-to-`SET` lists of possible values in parent and child table don't have to be the same. So I suspect that even if you could use VARCHAR, it wouldn't help you in any way with checking or forcing values integrity.

I would recommend using lookup table instead of `ENUM`. It's more flexible solution and there is less redundancy in metadata of your tables.